# The Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound

Tags: vb.net

am stuck. I connected a DataGridView to VB so that any information entered from it, should be automatically saved in the Access Database. I want to transfer data from the DatagridView to Microsoft Access tables but unfortunately error keeps stating "Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView rows collection when the control is data-bound". Is there anyway to assist me please? Thank you!

Here's the code.

```
    If TextBox3.Text = "" And TextBox4.Text = "" Then

        MsgBox("Enter Data")
    Else
        Dim Quantity As String = ListBox3.Text
    End If

    ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox3.Text.Trim())
    ListBox5.Items.Add(TextBox4.Text.Trim())
    ListBox3.Items.Add(TextBox5.Text.Trim())
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add("", ListBox1.Text, "", "", ListBox5.Text, ListBox3.Text)
```

Comment: The error message means what it says.  When a control is bound to a datasource, work with that datasource.  `DataGridView1.Rows.Add(...` isnt adding data to a datatable, its adding to the control.

Comment: i saw what the problem is and fixed it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you bind data to the grid then you need to add a new row to the [DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Here is short example:

```
Dim newRow As DataRow

newRow = dataSet.Tables(0).NewRow
newRow.Item(0) = txtValue1.Text
newRow.Item(1) = txtValue2.Text

dataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Add(newRow)
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I added a new row and it worked perfectly.